# How do you replace the content of html tags in vim?

Tags: html, regex, vim

For instance, if I want to replace `<person>Nancy</person>` with `<person>Henry</person>` for all occurrences of `<person>*</person>` in vim?

Currently, I have:

```
%s:/'<person>*<\/person>/<person>Henry<\/person>
```

But obviously, this is wrong.

Comment: Try `[^<]*`. `*` doesn't mean anything (you probably meant `.*` but that will capture too much).

Answer (score 4):

For a single substitution, Vim offers the handy `cit` (change inner tag) command.

For a global substitution, the answer depends on how well-structured your tag (soup) is. HTML / XML have a quite flexible syntax, so you can express the same content in various ways, and it becomes increasingly harder to construct a regular expression that matches them all. (Attempting to catch *all* cases is futile; see [this famous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454).)

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\v(<person>).\{-}(<\/person>)/\1Henry\2/g
```

does what you want but yeah, what Ingo said.

- `\v` means "very magic": it's a convenient way to avoid backslashitis.
- `(something)` (or `\(something\)` without the `\v` modifier) is a sub-expression, you can have up to nine of them in your search pattern and reuse those capture groups with `\1...\9` in your replacement pattern or even later in your search pattern. `\0` represents the whole match. Here, the opening tag is referenced as `\1` and the closing tag as `\2`.